# Why isn't my Wii U GameCube controller adapter and Gamecube controller working with my Switch?

Tags: controllers, nintendo-switch

As has been widely reported, with update 4.0 of the Switch OS, Gamecube controllers can now be used to play games on the Switch when connected to the Switch dock with a Nintendo first-party Wii U Gamecube adapter.

However, when I connect my Gamecube controller to my Switch dock via a Wii U adapter (all genuine Nintendo parts), the controller is not recognized by the Switch -- the only controller it shows as being connected are the pair of Joy-Cons.

My Switch is in its dock and it is (successfully) connected to a TV.

I have the Wii U Gamecube controller adapter connected to the Switch dock by plugging both USB-A cables from the adapter into the two USB-A ports on the outside of the Switch dock.

Things I've tried:

- Verifying that my Switch does have the version 4.0 OS update.
- Manually having the Switch detect new controllers by going to the "Change Grip/Order" screen and then pressing and/or holding the L and R buttons on the connected Gamecube controller. (Nothing happens.)
- Test the Wii U adapter and Gamecube controller with Smash Bros. for Wii U to verify they still work ok.
- Reboot the Switch. (Actually rebooting, not just putting it to sleep and waking it.)
- Unplug and replug the USB cables from the adapter into the Switch.
- Swap the order of the two USB cables from the adapter.
- Try different ports on the 4-port Wii U Gamecube adapter.
- Try using a different Gamecube controller.

Why isn't this working? How can I make my Switch recognize my Gamecube controller connected via a Wii U Gamecube controller adapter?

Answer (score 1):

The only things from your process that I see might be an issue are that:

- only the black USB-A cable needs to be connected from the adapter to the Switch dock
- and you have to hit both the L and R triggers on the Gamecube controller to link to to the Switch after you connect the adapter with the controllers attached.

Comment: I gave it another few tries, both with only the black USB cable connected, and both the black and gray cables connected. I'm definitely copiously hitting L and R, individually, together, and holding them down. No luck yet, but thanks anyway!